# How can I access a collection's custom properties using the interface?

Tags: interface, collections

Now that we have a dedicated panel for the Collections properties in the properties editor, I was hoping we could access a collection's custom properties interface like we can for the other objects in the other panels. However this is not available.

[image]

See for example the object properties :

[image]

How can I have access to the collection custom properties using only the interface ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT : Starting with Blender 3.3 this feature is in Blender by default. There is no need anymore to create a custom python addon.**

---

**For Blender up to 3.2 :**

As you may know in Blender, all objects inheriting from [ID (Object)](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) can hold custom properties. These are useful to store specific bits of information on objects. They can be accessed in many parts of Blender, and by the python API.

The [Collection](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Collection.html) types inherits from ID, so it supports custom properties.

This means we can add, read and delete custom properties on collections using the python API.

```
import bpy

collection = bpy.data.collections["Collection"]
collection["prop"] = 2
print(collection["prop"])
del(collection["prop"])
```

Are all supported.

However the interface doesn't allow us to have a direct access to these properties without using the API.

Thankfully we can re-use a built-in construct to provide this behaviour in a very low amount of code. We're going to write a script that can be imported as an add-on so the functionality is always available.

```
import bpy
from rna_prop_ui import PropertyPanel


bl_info = {
    "name": "Collection Custom Properties",
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "category": "Interface",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "author": "Gorgious56",
    "description": "Access Collection Custom Properties",
}


class GU_PT_collection_custom_properties(bpy.types.Panel, PropertyPanel): 
    _context_path = "collection"
    _property_type = bpy.types.Collection
    bl_label = "Custom Properties"
    bl_idname = "GU_PT_collection_custom_properties"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_context = "collection"


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(GU_PT_collection_custom_properties)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GU_PT_collection_custom_properties)


if __name__=="__main__":
    register()
```

Write this into a text file with your favorite notepad, then save & quit. Change the extension to `.py`. Your file should look like this :

[image]

Now go to Edit > Preferences > Add-on > Install and navigate to your file, click on "Install Add-on" and check the box in the new entry.

[image]

Result :

[image]

Credits to @Wahooney on Blenderartists : https://blenderartists.org/t/collections-with-custom-attributes/1142437/12